# How multi springboot module projects with diff context-path build to one jar?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

I have a project with several springboot  modules by gradle. They same like below:

```
myproject
  |--module-common
  |--module-a
  |--module-b
  |--module-c
```

Module a、b、c are web services,all dependent on common.

Most time a、b、c build itself as a.jar、b.jar、c.jar . Desploy with different application.properties, and my front page request them as [http://127.0.0.1/a/apis、http://127.0.0.1/b/apis、http://127.0.0.1/c/apis](http://127.0.0.1/a/apis%E3%80%81http://127.0.0.1/b/apis%E3%80%81http://127.0.0.1/c/apis)

But sometimes we need build a、b、c in to one jar, and the context-path still need with /a /b /c

How can I do it?

Can anyone give some ideas?

Thank you very much!

Help or give some ideas